# Theme injection in VScode extension

Tags: markdown, vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting

I want to develop a new extension for syntax highlighting(specifically an extension for some extended markdown grammars), and I need to define some new scopes to highlight.

I don't want to break the default theme highlighting, but if I define theme contributes in `package.json` and add new scope highlighting in a `.tmTheme` file, the engine will only highlight the scopes that I define, and any other scopes remains unhighlighted.

I wonder if there's any approach that I can both keep origin theme and add new highlighting to specific grammar.